# Combine single ndarray in certain positions

Tags: python, numpy

I just learned python
i want to ask about Ndarray numpy

for example, i have

`a = np.array([3, 2, 3, 9])`

how to duplicate `a` using looping.
desired like this

```
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

i have tried

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 2, 3, 9])
k = 3

for i in range(k):
    z = np.concatenate((a, a), axis=0)

print(z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of ways of doing this.  For a learner they are all instructive.

The `broadcasating` suggested in the other answer should be fast, but may be a bit hard to understand.

following your concatenate lead:

```
In [301]: a = np.array([3, 2, 3, 9])                                                             
In [302]: np.concatenate([a,a,a])                                                                
Out[302]: array([3, 2, 3, 9, 3, 2, 3, 9, 3, 2, 3, 9])
In [303]: np.concatenate([a,a,a]).reshape(3,4)                                                   
Out[303]: 
array([[3, 2, 3, 9],
       [3, 2, 3, 9],
       [3, 2, 3, 9]])
In [304]: np.concatenate([a,a,a]).reshape(3,4).T                                                 
Out[304]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

Or since you want to arange the values vertically:

```
In [306]: a[:,None]                                                                              
Out[306]: 
array([[3],
       [2],
       [3],
       [9]])
In [307]: a[:,None].repeat(3,1)                                                                  
Out[307]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

another way:

```
In [308]: np.outer(a,np.ones(3,int))                                                             
Out[308]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

or do the outer with broadcasting:

```
In [309]: a[:,None]*np.ones(3,int)                                                               
Out[309]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

With a list repeat:

```
In [311]: np.concatenate([a[:,None]]*3, axis=1)                                                  
Out[311]: 
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [9, 9, 9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `broadcast_to`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([3, 2, 3, 9])
k = 3
print(np.broadcast_to(a, (k, 4)).T)
# array([[3, 3, 3],
#        [2, 2, 2],
#        [3, 3, 3],
#        [9, 9, 9]])
```

Comment: what if i use looping?

Comment: Do you need to use Python loops? Native NumPy functions are much, much, faster than their Python equivalents (they're executed in C).

Comment: someone please help